# NSDictionary Not Writing To File (Objective c mac os app)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The variable "vocabList" is a NSDictionary that contains values in it and the variable "_saveName" is just a user entered string from a NSTextField. When I run the project in xcode 5, everything works fine and I can find the .archive file in the finder. However, when I archive the product and run it as a .app, it does not create a .archive file. Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:vocabList toFile:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.archive", [_saveName stringValue]]];
```

Comment: Log the *full* path where you're creating the file.  I'll bet it's not where you think it is.  (Or just search for the file in Finder.)

Comment: As @HotLicks says, the file is likely in your app's sandbox directory or another location since the full path may not be specified

Comment: @HotLicks no, its not there. i even tried it with the "path finder" application and it still couldn't be located.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the path an absolute path (i.e. does it start with a slash)?

Comment: @Chuck isn't the default path (with no ./ slashes) the same level as the application?

Comment: @user3011439: AFAIK the working directory isn't guaranteed to be any particular value. You shouldn't rely on it. If you want to find your app bundle, you can use the NSBundle methods to do that, but always calculate your paths relative to some absolute root when you're using AppKit.

Comment: @Chuck thanks, it worked when I used an absolute path.

Comment: This sounds crazy, but the standard here is to post your own answer below as an answer and then accept yourself, so that everyone else will see that this question is solved.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread this, you’re totally right, it’s Chuck’s catch. (Well, HotLicks also was on the path, as was sbooth...Your call guys.)